# 80s-90s Anthology series with an episode with a boy and girl rapidly aged in a forest by a malevolent force

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember an anthology series of the late eighties / early nineties. In one episode a boy and girl go into a mysterious forest They encounter a malevolent force and begin to age. The girl dies. The boy manages to get away but still appears an old man. Doctors cannot help him and advise him to make the most of what years he has left. The episode finishes with a voice over. Can anyone remember which series this was?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.